# Existence of a Hölder-free space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, metric-spaces

The Lipschitz-free or Arens-Eells space over a pointed separable metric space $(X,0,d)$ is a well-studied object.  My question is, is an analogos Hölder-free space; for a fixed Hölder constant $\alpha>0$?

Comment: My intuition is that such an $\alpha$-Holder-free space would be the Lipschitz-free space of the snowflaking $(X,0,d^{\alpha})$; granted that $\alpha \in (0,1]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kalton [Collect. Math. 55 (2004), no. 2, 171–217] studied several versions of such spaces, see the definitions on page 180. This paper was reprinted in Nigel J. Kalton selecta. Vol. 2. Birkhäuser/Springer, 2016.

Comment: Thanks very much Mikhail.  I'll take a look now

Answer (score 4):

As AIM_BLB says in the comments, every Holder space of exponent $\alpha < 1$ is a Lipschitz space with respect to the metric $d^\alpha$. So the answer is an immediate "yes". May I add that I discuss Holder spaces at length in my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (2nd edition).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will definitely look that up asap.

Comment: You are welcome!